# How to get values from 2 dimensional array and store them into a single variable?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I have an array named `$products`, which contains let's say 2 different products which are also arrays:

```
$products[0] = array("product_name"=>"Honda", "product_id"=>001)
```

and

```
$products[1] = array("product_name"=>"Hyundai", "product_id"=>002)
```

I would like to go through all the products in `$products` and store the names of every product into a single string variable named `$allProductsNames`- so that when I echo this variable the result will be:

```
echo $allProductsNames;   //will print a string: Honda, Hyundai
```

I guess, the the base for that code is:

```
foreach ($products as $key => $product)
{
    /* extracting every $product['product_name']
       and storing it into $allProductsNames */
}
```

I would appreciate Your help with the rest of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with the array_column and implode functions.

```
echo implode(', ', array_column($products, 'product_name'));
```

Comment: Nice one with `array_column`

Answer (score 0):

You can start by adding all the `product_name` values from `$products` into `$allProductsNames` and then use `implode()` to print in out.

```
$allProductsNames = "";

foreach($products as $product){
  $allProductsNames[] = $product['product_name'];
}

echo  implode(', ', $allProductsNames );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$allProductsNames = [];

foreach($products as $product)
{
    foreach($product as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($key === 'product_name')
        {
            array_push($allProductsNames, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

You mean something like this?